# What does the grey progression bar represent in TeraCopy?

Tags: windows-7, teracopy

I use TeraCopy with Windows 7. What does the grey progression bar represent in TeraCopy when copying files?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your showing there is the buffer fill, that part of the file data is in the memory.
One method that terracopy uses to speed stuff up is to use its own memory allocation to buffer the data being transferred, this is especially useful when copying data from the same hardware item (disk) back to the same hardware item, to send more of it to the ram first.
There are options to instead use windows own buffer.

I colorise mine, so mine is not grey :-)